# positioning geom_boxplot to top of figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to be able to great a figure that incorporates a geom_boxplot(), geom_histogram(), and geom_rug() call to ggplot(). I wasn't sure how to go about moving the position of the geom_boxplot() output to the top of the figure without hard-coding the `ymax` and `ymin` values. It would be great to know how to let ggplot figure this one out based on the outcome of the effect of a particular argument to geom_histogram's `binwidth`.

For instance, given these data:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  counts=ceiling(runif(n = 100, min = 100, max = 1000)),
  sampleID=paste0("sample-",seq(1,100)))
```

and this function:

```
ggplot(df, aes(counts)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) +
  geom_rug(sides = "b") +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

The output is a box plot along the bottom of the figure:

[image]

However, I'd prefer it to be above all the vertical bars of the histogram. In this particular instance, I might manually alter the image because I now know what the maximum value of y is:

```
ggplot(df, aes(counts)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) +
  geom_rug(sides = "b") +
  geom_boxplot(ymin=4.5, ymax=5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5), breaks = c(0,2,4)) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Nevertheless, I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could instruct me how to create this type of plot without the need for manual adjustments.

Thank you for your consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(counts)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) +
  geom_rug(sides = "b") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5), breaks = c(0,2,4)) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

ub <- max(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$count)
p + geom_boxplot(ymin = ub + 0.5, ymax = ub + 1, y = ub + 0.75)
```

Note that if you just set `ymin` and `ymax`, the whiskers are disconnected lines at `y = 0`, which is probably not what you want.

Instead of the last line, you can also map `y` instead, like so:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(y = upper + 0.5))
```

Then `width` controls the size of the box.